# In chrome, how can it show the full size image url when user drag a thumbnail image in my website?

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

We show thumbnail images to save bandwidth.

However, when user drag a thumbnail image to another browser tab, we wants to show the full size image.

The image is not a link.

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply make the image a link to the full size image. It should then open the link when the thumbnail is dragged, opening the full sized image.

edit: eg.

```
<a href="large-image1.jpg"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" /></a>
```